# Execute stored procedure using openrowset without doing with result sets for every column

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute a stored procedure using `openrowset`, which has dynamic SQL in it, it throws an error

> Contains dynamic SQL. Consider using WITH RESULT SETS

An example is as follows.

```
select output.* 
from openrowset ('SQLOLEDB','SERVER=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                 'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON; exec storedproc ') as output
```

Since I have many output parameters, is there a simple way to display all the columns?

Note: I have to use `openrowset` as the stored procedure is being executed inside a script (R).

I also tried the following but didn't work.

```
declare @sqlstmt nvarchar(max)
declare @queryout nvarchar(max)
set @queryout = 'storedproc   @parameter1=''''D'''', @param2=''''08/19/2018'''',  '
set @queryout  = '''exec ' + @queryout 
set @sqlstmt = N'select outputprod.* from openrowset (''SQLOLEDB'',''SERVER=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;'' , ' + @queryout + ''') as outputprod'
print(@sqlstmt)
exec (@sqlstmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic Query with full select statement inside `varchar` variable then execute it with `EXEC`. [see here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).

for example

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)
SET @columnList = 'CustomerID, ContactName, City'
SET @city = '''London'''
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = ' + @city
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: Executing the query as a standalone is not an issue. But I need it to execute it as part of openrowset as the result will be stored in a dataframe in R.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Stored procedure with `output parameter` to return the generated query, to avoid dynamic stored procedure being passed.

```
DECLARE @queryout NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @sqlstmt NVARCHAR(max)
EXEC storedproc @queryout OUTPUT 
SET @sqlstmt = N'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;' + @queryout
select output.* from openrowset  (
'SQLOLEDB','SERVER=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;', @sqlstmt) as output
```

Comment: Tried this method and posted the sample query that I used. But still not working.

Comment: I don't have any control to make changes to the stored procedure. I am only a consumer to the stored proc.